# How to implement a boost::variant derived-class?

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, derived-class, boost-variant

I have tried for hours to code a class deriving from `boost::variant`. But I do not understand what is the problem (I do not understand what the compilation error means).

**What are the rules to implement a clean `boost::variant` derived-class?**

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>

class MyVariant : public boost::variant<char,bool>
{
public:    
       MyVariant ()          : boost::variant<char,bool>( ) {}

       template <typename T>
       MyVariant(      T& v) : boost::variant<char,bool>(v) {}

       template <typename T>
       MyVariant(const T& v) : boost::variant<char,bool>(v) {}
};

int main ()
{
      MyVariant a;
      MyVariant b = a;        //compilation error
  //  MyVariant c = MyVariant();
  //  MyVariant d (true);
  //  MyVariant e ('E');
}
```

**Why do I want to use inheritance?** (EDIT to give more details to @zaufi)

- I want an empty state
- I want to accept `const char*` as `string`
- I want to accept `int` as `long`
- I want to give `enum` types

For instance, in pseudo C++ code, my hopes:

```
class MyVariant : public boost::variant<char,bool,long,std::string>
{
  typedef boost::variant<char,bool,long,std::string> super;

public:    

  // I know here I should specialize templeted constructors
  // but I is more clear like that, isn't it?    
  MyVariant()              : super('e')             {} //empty -> char
  MyVariant(char        c) : super(std::string(1,c)){} //char  -> string
  MyVariant(const char* s) : super(std::string(s) ) {} //char* -> string
  MyVariant(int         v) : super(long       (v) ) {} //TODO boundaries    
  /* other constructors ... */

  enum Type
  {
    NONE,  //my empty state = char type
    BOOL,
    LONG,
    STRING
  };

  Type type() const { return (Type) which(); }    
};
```

**The basic snippet code (on top of the question) has been tested on different platforms**

- boost v1.33 + GCC 4.1 (Linux)
- boost v1.52 + GCC 4.7 (MinGW)
- boost v1.52 + Visual C++ 2010 (v10)

Below my errors for the two versions of GCC 
(I can remove one of the both if it bothers someone...)

---

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52)
Copyright (C) 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ g++ myVariant.cpp
/usr/include/boost/variant/variant.hpp: In constructor 'boost::variant<T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, T16, T17, T18, T19>::variant(T&) [with T = MyVariant, T0_ = char, T1 = bool, T2 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T3 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T4 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T5 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T6 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T7 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T8 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T9 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T10 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T11 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T12 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T13 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T14 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T15 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T16 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T17 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T18 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T19 = boost::detail::variant::void_]':
myVariant.cpp:10:   instantiated from 'MyVariant::MyVariant(T&) [with T = MyVariant]'
myVariant.cpp:19:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/boost/variant/variant.hpp:1348: error: call of overloaded 'convert_construct(MyVariant&, long int)' is ambiguous
/usr/include/boost/variant/variant.hpp:1262: note: candidates are: void boost::variant<T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, T16, T17, T18, T19>::convert_construct(T&, int, mpl_::false_) [with T = MyVariant, T0_ = char, T1 = bool, T2 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T3 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T4 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T5 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T6 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T7 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T8 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T9 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T10 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T11 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T12 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T13 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T14 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T15 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T16 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T17 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T18 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T19 = boost::detail::variant::void_]
/usr/include/boost/variant/variant.hpp:1321: note:                 void boost::variant<T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, T16, T17, T18, T19>::convert_construct(boost::variant<U0, U1, U2, U3, U4, U5, U6, U7, U8, U9, U10, U11, U12, U13, U14, U15, U16, U17, U18, U19>&, long int) [with U0 = char, U1 = bool, U2 = boost::detail::variant::void_, U3 = boost::detail::variant::void_, U4 = boost::detail::variant::void_, U5 = boost::detail::variant::void_, U6 = boost::detail::variant::void_, U7 = boost::detail::variant::void_, U8 = boost::detail::variant::void_, U9 = boost::detail::variant::void_, U10 = boost::detail::variant::void_, U11 = boost::detail::variant::void_, U12 = boost::detail::variant::void_, U13 = boost::detail::variant::void_, U14 = boost::detail::variant::void_, U15 = boost::detail::variant::void_, U16 = boost::detail::variant::void_, U17 = boost::detail::variant::void_, U18 = boost::detail::variant::void_, U19 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T0_ = char, T1 = bool, T2 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T3 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T4 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T5 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T6 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T7 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T8 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T9 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T10 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T11 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T12 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T13 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T14 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T15 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T16 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T17 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T18 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T19 = boost::detail::variant::void_]
/usr/include/boost/variant/variant.hpp:1330: note:                 void boost::variant<T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, T16, T17, T18, T19>::convert_construct(const boost::variant<U0, U1, U2, U3, U4, U5, U6, U7, U8, U9, U10, U11, U12, U13, U14, U15, U16, U17, U18, U19>&, long int) [with U0 = char, U1 = bool, U2 = boost::detail::variant::void_, U3 = boost::detail::variant::void_, U4 = boost::detail::variant::void_, U5 = boost::detail::variant::void_, U6 = boost::detail::variant::void_, U7 = boost::detail::variant::void_, U8 = boost::detail::variant::void_, U9 = boost::detail::variant::void_, U10 = boost::detail::variant::void_, U11 = boost::detail::variant::void_, U12 = boost::detail::variant::void_, U13 = boost::detail::variant::void_, U14 = boost::detail::variant::void_, U15 = boost::detail::variant::void_, U16 = boost::detail::variant::void_, U17 = boost::detail::variant::void_, U18 = boost::detail::variant::void_, U19 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T0_ = char, T1 = bool, T2 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T3 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T4 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T5 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T6 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T7 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T8 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T9 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T10 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T11 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T12 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T13 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T14 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T15 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T16 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T17 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T18 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T19 = boost::detail::variant::void_]
```

---

```
$ g++ --version
g++.exe (GCC) 4.7.2
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ g++ myVariant.cpp -I /c/.../include/
In file included from c:/.../include/boost/variant.hpp:17:0,
                 from myVariant.cpp:1:
c:/.../include/boost/variant/variant.hpp: In instantiation of 'boost::variant<T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, T16, T17, T18, T19>::variant(T&) [with T = MyVariant; T0_ = char; T1 = bool; T2 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T3 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T4 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T5 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T6 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T7 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T8 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T9 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T10 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T11 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T12 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T13 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T14 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T15 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T16 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T17 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T18 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T19 = boost::detail::variant::void_]':
myVariant.cpp:9:66:   required from 'MyVariant::MyVariant(T&) [with T = MyVariant]'
myVariant.cpp:18:25:   required from here
c:/.../include/boost/variant/variant.hpp:1406:9: error: call of overloaded convert_construct(MyVariant&, long int)' is ambiguous
c:/.../include/boost/variant/variant.hpp:1406:9: note: candidates are:
c:/.../include/boost/variant/variant.hpp:1316:10: note: void boost::variant<T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, T16, T17, T18, T19>::convert_construct(T&, int, mpl_::false_) [with T = MyVariant; T0_ = char; T1 = bool; T2 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T3 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T4 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T5 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T6 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T7 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T8 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T9 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T10 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T11 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T12 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T13 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T14 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T15 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T16 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T17 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T18 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T19 = boost::detail::variant::void_; mpl_::false_ = mpl_::bool_<false>]
c:/.../include/boost/variant/variant.hpp:1376:10: note: void boost::variant<T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, T16, T17, T18, T19>::convert_construct(boost::variant<U0, U1, U2, U3, U4, U5, U6, U7, U8, U9, U10, U11, U12, U13, U14, U15, U16, U17, U18, U19>&, long int) [with U0 = char; U1 = bool; U2 = boost::detail::variant::void_; U3 = boost::detail::variant::void_; U4 = boost::detail::variant::void_; U5 = boost::detail::variant::void_; U6 = boost::detail::variant::void_; U7 = boost::detail::variant::void_; U8 = boost::detail::variant::void_; U9 = boost::detail::variant::void_; U10 = boost::detail::variant::void_; U11 = boost::detail::variant::void_; U12 = boost::detail::variant::void_; U13 = boost::detail::variant::void_; U14 = boost::detail::variant::void_; U15 = boost::detail::variant::void_; U16 = boost::detail::variant::void_; U17 = boost::detail::variant::void_; U18 = boost::detail::variant::void_; U19 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T0_ = char; T1 = bool; T2 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T3 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T4 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T5 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T6 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T7 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T8 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T9 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T10 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T11 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T12 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T13 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T14 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T15 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T16 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T17 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T18 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T19 = boost::detail::variant::void_]
c:/.../include/boost/variant/variant.hpp:1385:10: note: void boost::variant<T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, T16, T17, T18, T19>::convert_construct(const boost::variant<U0, U1, U2, U3, U4, U5, U6, U7, U8, U9, U10, U11, U12, U13, U14, U15, U16, U17, U18, U19>&, long int) [with U0 = char; U1 = bool; U2 = boost::detail::variant::void_; U3 = boost::detail::variant::void_; U4 = boost::detail::variant::void_; U5 = boost::detail::variant::void_; U6 = boost::detail::variant::void_; U7 = boost::detail::variant::void_; U8 = boost::detail::variant::void_; U9 = boost::detail::variant::void_; U10 = boost::detail::variant::void_; U11 = boost::detail::variant::void_; U12 = boost::detail::variant::void_; U13 = boost::detail::variant::void_; U14 = boost::detail::variant::void_; U15 = boost::detail::variant::void_; U16 = boost::detail::variant::void_; U17 = boost::detail::variant::void_; U18 = boost::detail::variant::void_; U19 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T0_ = char; T1 = bool; T2 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T3 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T4 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T5 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T6 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T7 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T8 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T9 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T10 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T11 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T12 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T13 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T14 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T15 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T16 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T17 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T18 = boost::detail::variant::void_; T19 = boost::detail::variant::void_]
```

Comment: Boost variant doesn't have a virtual destructor (or any other virtual functions), indicating that it's not intended to be used as a base class. IOW, the simple rule for how to implement a clean boost::variant derived class is: "You can't. Don't even try!"

Comment: @JerryCoffin: I do not require `virtual` destructor, because I do not intend to implement any destructor (i.e. I do not use `new` in the constructor). Nevertheless I still hope there is a way to derive from `boost::variant`...

Comment: @olibre: what do you want to achieve by using inheritance?

Comment: @olibre: what Jerry is concerned about is that you might write `boost::variant<char,bool> *p = new MyVariant(); delete p;`. That would have undefined behavior regardless of what the destructor of `MyVariant` looks like or whether you defined a destructor at all.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Ok thanks ;) I have forgotten that

Comment: @zaufi: I have given my hopes (just finished to edit my question). Therefore, about you, how to meet them?

Comment: @olibre: to implement what you want (despite of its strangeness) you still don't need to inherit. I can give you an example, but I still need some details: I don't see any `long` nor `int` types in a list of underlaid variant's types... what exact list of types do you want to have? what conversions do you want to have?

Comment: @olibre: btw, the reason for error you've got, is in your template consctuctors -- both are **NOT copy constructors** you've instantiated by `MyVariant b = a` expresion... and `MyVarian` is not in a list of variant's underlaid types!

Comment: @zaufi: I do not want `int` underlying type, just `long`. In my hope example (second snippet code), you can imagine the presence of the templated constructor from the first snippet. Please, let me know if you still do not see what I want. Moreover I do not know how to implement the copy-constructor within the first snippet. I have attempted `MyVariant(const MyVariant& v) : boost::variant<char,bool>(v) {}` but compiler complains (on the line of the copy-constructor GCC says `error: call of overloaded 'convert_construct(const MyVariant&, long int)' is ambiguous`)

Comment: @Jerry Coffin no virtual descructor means it's not intended to be used as a polymorphic base class

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The accepted answer and the other answers do not answer the question. There are good reasons to derive from boost::variant.

- you want to add methods into the variant, so that it behaves more polymorphic
- you want to keep using `boost::apply_visitor(visitor(), variant)` without jumping through hoops

Here is a working example of a type `MyVariant` inheriting from `boost::variant`. The code requires C++11 to inherit the (complex) constructors of `boost::variant`.

**Edit:** Operators such as equal comparison implemented in `boost::variant` do not automatically work for the derived class. This is a (unintended) consequence of how `boost::variant` is implemented, it explicitly prevents comparisons to "foreign" types using templates. Operators can be enabled with explicit overloads, as shown in the example.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<boost/variant.hpp>

struct type_size_visitor : public boost::static_visitor<unsigned> {
  template <typename T>
  unsigned operator()(const T&) const { return sizeof(T); }
};

template <typename... Types>
class MyVariant : public boost::variant<Types...>
{
  using base_type = boost::variant<Types...>;
public:
  // inherit constructors
  using base_type::base_type;

  // add a new method
  unsigned type_size() { return boost::apply_visitor(type_size_visitor(), *this); }

  /* Inheriting operators from boost::variant does not
     work as it normally would. We have to add explicit
     overloads for the operators we want to use.
  */
  bool operator==(const MyVariant& rhs) const {
    // cast rhs to base and delegate to operator in base
    return base_type::operator==(static_cast<const base_type&>(rhs));
  }
};

int main() {
  MyVariant<std::string, char> v;
  v = 1;
  std::cout << v.type_size() << " " << sizeof(char) << std::endl;
  v = std::string("foo");
  std::cout << v.type_size() << " " << sizeof(std::string) << std::endl;

  // comparison operators need workaround shown above
  MyVariant<std::string, char> a, b;
  a = 1; b = 1;
  assert(a == b);
}
```

Comment: Nice answer,  is it possible to inherit additional semantics as well, for example comparison and operators ??

Comment: @AKludges: I extended the answer in a reply to you.

Comment: Hello, I tried the given code, I receive an error in clang:
`error: invalid operands to binary expression ('std::__1::basic_ostream<char>' and 'const ifcinteger')
        out_ << operand;`

Comment: @nmd_07 I looks like you are missing an overload for operator<< with arguments basic_ostream and your custom type ifcinteger. Just implement the missing overload. I think this is not related to my answer.

Answer (score 4):

> I want an empty state

```
boost::variant<boost::blank, bool, long, std::string>
```

There. That was much easier. No need for messy inheritance.

> I want to give enum types

```
enum Type
{
  NONE,
  BOOL,
  LONG,
  STRING
};

struct GetType : public boost::static_visitor<Type>
{
  Type operator()(boost::blank) {return NONE;}
  Type operator()(bool) {return BOOL;}
  Type operator()(long) {return LONG;}
  Type operator()(const std::string&) {return STRING;}
};

//Get the type
Type t = boost::apply_visitor(GetType(), theData);
```

That was easy too. Plus, if you add a new type to the variant, your code will break if you don't update `GetType` to match.

The other two criteria require you to use a class, but you don't need inheritance. You need containment.

```
typedef boost::variant<boost::blank, std::string, long> VarType;

class MyVariant
{
public:
    //Default construction will initialize with boost::blank.
    MyVariant(char c) : m_var(std::string(1,c)) {}
    MyVariant(const char* s) : m_var(std::string(s)) {}
    MyVariant(int v) : m_var(long(v)) {}
    MyVariant(long v) : m_var(long(v)) {}

    VarType &operator *() {return m_var;}
    const VarType &operator *() const {return m_var;}

private:
    VarType m_var;
};

...

Type t = boost::apply_visitor(GetType(), *theData);
```

Comment: Is it definitely better to call that last pair of member functions `operator*` than it is to call them `get()`? The Law of Demeter people will hunt you down and kill you either way.

Comment: @SteveJessop: He wants to write a class for the sole purpose of not having to type `std::string(...)` and `long(...)` when he passes values into it. Conciseness is obviously a factor; if it were my code, I wouldn't even make it a new class.

Comment: Thank you @NicolBolas. You understood users of my library want to write `MyVariant v = "string";`. I also want my library detects when users do not assign any value (or unset `MyVariant`). Cheers

Comment: @NicolBolas: using visitor for type retrieval is a very good idea but consumes little bit more resources than a basic `variant::which()` bypass. Even if the visitor is less error prone (compilation error on type inconsistency) I would still choose `Type type() const { return (Type) which(); }`. What is your opinion?

Answer (score 0):

Finally my implementation based on **Nicol Bolas**'s answer:

**`Variant.h`**

```
class Variant 
{
  public:
  Variant()                     : v_(boost::blank()) {}
  Variant(bool     v)           : v_(v)              {}
  Variant(long     v)           : v_(v)              {}
  Variant(int      v)           : v_(long(v))        {}
  Variant(double   v)           : v_(v)              {}
  Variant(const std::string& s) : v_(s)              {}
  Variant(const char*        s) : v_(std::string(s)) {}

  typedef boost::variant <boost::blank, bool, 
                          long, double, std::string> bstvar;
  enum Type {                      
    NONE, BOOL,          // above underlying types
    LONG, DOUBLE, STRING // and enum must be consistent:
  };                     // (order must be same)

  operator          bstvar&  ()       { return v_; }
  operator    const bstvar&  () const { return v_; }
  bstvar      &     operator*()       { return v_; }
  bstvar const&     operator*() const { return v_; }
  bool              empty    () const { return  type() == NONE;          }
  bool              toBool   () const { return  boost::get<bool  > (v_); }
  long              toLong   () const { return  boost::get<long  > (v_); }
  double            toDouble () const { return  boost::get<double> (v_); }
  std::string const& toStr   () const { return  boost::get<std::string> (v_); }
  std::string      & toStr   ()       { return  boost::get<std::string> (v_); }
  inline Type        type    () const { return  (Type) v_.which();       }
  static Type        type    (const std::string&);
  static std::string type    (Type t);

  private:  bstvar v_;  // Data
};
```

**`Variant.cpp`**

```
#include "Variant.h"
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm> //std::transform

Variant::Type   Variant::type   (const std::string& str)
{
  std::string lower = str;
  std::transform (lower.begin(), lower.end(), lower.begin(), ::tolower);

  if (lower == "bool")     return BOOL;
  if (lower == "long")     return LONG;
  if (lower == "double")   return DOUBLE;
  if (lower == "string")   return STRING;
  else                     return NONE;
}

std::string  Variant::type  (Type t)
{
  switch (t)
  {
    case NONE:    return "none";
    case BOOL:    return "bool";
    case LONG:    return "long";
    case DOUBLE:  return "double";
    case STRING:  return "string";

    default:
      ;//see below
  }
  std::ostringstream oss;
  oss <<"Unexpected type="<< t;
  return oss.str();
}
```